# Nodejs Redis hdel will not remove key

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm really stumped here, hoping sombody can help out.

I have a very basic redis app that is using hset with a single key. When I go to remove the key via

myRedis.hdel(room,mysocket,function(err,response){

```
        })
```

It will return 1 from the response, telling me it removed it. Looking at it though the key is still there?

What is odd, when I place the id explicitly, it will work, so if I do something like

myRedis.hdel(room,"key",function(err,response){

```
        })
```

It removed it, however doing it via the variable its a no-go. Any idea what might be happening? I have tried wrapping it in quotes and the like but still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like redis is a bit picky about key names. I was using a randomly generated socket.id from socket.io as the key. Once I appended "socket-" to the front of each key in redis it started working..

Not sure if that is documented anywhere or not but seemed to fix my issue.